# Built up a class using Roslyn... now how do I actually compile it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, code-generation, roslyn

I'm trying to some old .net code to .net Core. I'm not too familiar with what i'm converting over, but it's some simple code gen using CodeDom. From what I can tell, this means I need to use Roslyn in .net Core.

This is what I had in the old code:

```
var thing = new CodeTypeDeclaration("test");
wrapper.IsClass = true;
wrapper.TypeAttributes = TypeAttributes.Public;

AddPropertyHelper(thing, typeof(string), "some_prop");
...
...
...
var compiler = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
var options = new CompilerParameters();
options.GenerateExecutable = false;
options.GenerateInMemory = true;
options.OutputAssembly = Path.GetTempFileName();
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(options);
return results.CompiledAssembly.GetType(GeneratedNamespace + "." + "test");
```

and this is what I have so far in Roslyn:

```
var @namespace = SyntaxFactory.NamespaceDeclaration(SyntaxFactory.ParseName(GeneratedNamespace));
var classDeclaration = SyntaxFactory.ClassDeclaration("test");
classDeclaration.AddModifiers(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword));
AddPropertyToWrapped(classDeclaration, typeof(string), "some_prop");
```

**Edit: this is what i've added**
**---**

```
var cu = SyntaxFactory.CompilationUnit();
cu.AddMembers(@namespace);
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(
            "foo",
            syntaxTrees: new[] { cu.SyntaxTree },
            options: options,
            references: new[] {
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Uri).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(coreDir.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "mscorlib.dll"),
                MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(coreDir.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "System.Runtime.dll")
            });
var ms = new MemoryStream();
var emitResult = compilation.Emit(ms);
```

**---**

I don't see anything about "compiling" it though. I haven't find any useful examples online or documentation that wasn't just overly complex. Is there something simple i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`CSharpCompilation.Create()` method](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Compilation/CSharpCompilation.cs,201), which takes SyntaxTrees and references.

You can then call its various `Emit()` methods to compile to a stream.

Comment: Do you know of any examples? I've tried finding some, but none that are trying to accomplish the same thing as me. I've added a compilation unit, but i'm not sure what I need to do with Emit.

Comment: You need a `CSharpCompilation`, not a `CompilationUnitSyntax`.  Calling its `Create()` will give you an object with an object with a bunch of `Emit()` overloads (some of which are extension methods).  That will give a stream with an assembly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot where I was when I made this yesterday. I've added a few things (added OP), and now the result of Emit() has no failures. I have the stream, but i'm not sure what to actually do with that... I've seen some old examples where people do    var ourAssembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());, but that doesn't work anymore; Assembly.Load expects a AssemblyName, not a byte stream.